# How to display the rendered entity of a store in the purchase funnel?

Tags: 8, theming, commerce

I created a link that displays the "Terms and Conditions" of the store to which the shopping cart relates in a modal window.

This link a page in a modal window.

I want to replace the page rendered by the store's rendered entity with the `cgv` display mode (this is the machine name of the display mode in my store type).

What should I change in my code ?

my_module/src/Plugin/Commerce/CheckoutPane/MarketplaceTermsAndConditions.php :

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\commerce_marketplace_terms_and_conditions\Plugin\Commerce\CheckoutPane;

use Drupal\Component\Serialization\Json;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\commerce_checkout\Plugin\Commerce\CheckoutPane\CheckoutPaneBase;
use Drupal\commerce_checkout\Plugin\Commerce\CheckoutPane\CheckoutPaneInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Link;
use Drupal\Core\Url;

class MarketplaceTermsAndConditions extends CheckoutPaneBase implements CheckoutPaneInterface {

  public function buildPaneForm(array $pane_form, FormStateInterface $form_state, array &$complete_form) {
    $store_name = $this->order->getStore()->getName();
    $store_id = $this->order->getStoreId();
    $pane_form['#attached']['library'][] = 'core/drupal.dialog.ajax';
    $attributes = [
      'attributes' => [
        'class' => 'use-ajax',
        'data-dialog-type' => 'modal',
        'data-dialog-options' => Json::encode([
          'width' => 'auto'
        ]),
      ],
    ];
    $link = Link::fromTextAndUrl(
      $this->t('terms and conditions of the store "@store_name"', ['@store_name' => $store_name]),
      Url::fromUri("internal:/store/$store_id/cgv", $attributes)
    )->toString();
    $pane_form['marketplace_terms_and_conditions'] = [
      '#type' => 'checkbox',
      '#default_value' => FALSE,
      '#title' => $this->t('I have read and accept @terms.', ['@terms' => $link]),
      '#required' => TRUE,
      '#weight' => $this->getWeight(),
    ];
    return $pane_form;
  }

}
```